# Angular: How to use ng-options to make four separate selections?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

JS:

```
angular
.module('app', [])

function MainCtrl() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.selectionList = [
        { id: 1, name: 'apple'},
        { id: 2, name: 'banana'},
        { id: 3, name: 'grapes'},
        { id: 4, name: 'carrot'}
    ];

    ctrl.selectedThing = ctrl.selectionList[0].name; 

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 unit">
        <select 
        ng-model="ctrl.selectedThing"
        ng-options="selections.name as selections.name for selections in ctrl.selectionList">
        </select>
    </div>

</div><!--end of first row-->
```

So this code creates four different selections.
The problem is that when I choose an option, let's say for example "apples" on one selection, all the other selections become apples too. Is there any way to solve this with ng-options or should I just write the select in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use ng-options, as that isn't the issue here. The problem you are seeing is most likely because the ng-model on all of your select elements is the same ctrl variable. So when you update one of them, it changes a single variable that is bound to all four dropdowns. You either need to setup up an array for your selected items, or four different instances of a selected variable.

```
ctrl.selectedThings = [ctrl.selectedList[0].name, '', '', ''];
```

Then in your view you can do this...

```
<select 
        ng-model="ctrl.selectedThings[rowIndex]"
        ng-options="selections.name as selections.name for selections in ctrl.selectionList">
        </select>
```

Not the most robust solution if you are going past 4 items, but you should be able to adapt it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, can you check and confirm?!

```js
(function ()
{
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    function HomeController()
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.selectionList = [
            { id: 1, name: 'apple'},
            { id: 2, name: 'banana'},
            { id: 3, name: 'grapes'},
            { id: 4, name: 'carrot'}
        ];

    }

    app.controller("HomeController", [HomeController]);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular JS App</title>        
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeController as homeCtrl">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 unit">
                    <select
                            ng-model="homeCtrl.selectedThing"
                            ng-options="selections.name as selections.name for selections in homeCtrl.selectionList">
                    </select>
                    <pre>{{homeCtrl.selectedThing}}</pre>
                </div>

            </div><!--end of first row-->
           
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, I want 4 of those selection menus (not options). The problem is that when I choose 'apple' for ONE selection, all the other three selection menus also take the value of apple.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your terminology. How 4 selection menus?! Make it clearer please?! The issue you are facing is due to same ng-model but make it clearer what is your case?! Your code adds one select with 4 options not 4 different selections?!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ng-model="ctrl.selectedThing"` for all of your `<select>` tags, they will all change to the same selection because they're using the same scope property. Think of it like having 4 variables referencing the same data: if you change one, access any of the variables will retrieve the same result.

You need to bind all of your selects to a different property on scope, so `ctrl.selectedThing1,2,...n`. That's not very scalable, but that would fix your problem.